# Strange facebook iframe app problem only in IE (I am using IE8)

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having same problem with facebook iframe based application in IE8, breaking layout is another thing but problem what I am having is show so small portion of app. It once shows the app and then redirect and show less portion, I think it is by auto resizing function of facebook. I guess problem is here in this portion of code:

```
             window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      'appId'   : '<?php echo $app_id; ?>',
      'session' : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it 
      'status'  : true, // check login status
      'cookie'  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      'xfbml'   : true // parse XFBML
    });

    // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
 };
```

So is problem in this part? please tell what do you think? It is working fine in other 3 major browsers and unfortunately IE  is 4th major browser.Any idea would be appreciated.
And yes it also pointed towards some facebook connect js file's error but I don't think it is related to it.

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Is this a canvas application, or is this implemented outside of Facebook (using the JS SDK)?  Also, to clarify, the issue is that it's reloading oddly, or that login is failing entirely?

Comment: It is a canvas application and it is now working fine, I think this is the problem with IE as it some times don't load the content properly and some times it reloads, but now it is working fine , I think this is the only change: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was the problem actually of fb. and IE and it happens in some other apps. also but it is running fine now in MSIE8 also and I think this is the tag that was required.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the same call in body tag on-load

```
<body onLoad="FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();">
```